# How to prevent multiple login in same browser using php

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables, redirect

It's php session problem.. where user's can login multiple times.. on same browser with same/different credentials..

1) User1 logged in ..

2) User1 Try to open LoginIndex.php in new tab..

3) It's showing the LoginIndex.php page instead of Previous Logged in page(User1 logged in)...

4) Accepting the User1 to login again with same/different credentials.. in same browser

I don't know why it is taking the login values again..

Here is the snippet of LoginViewController.php

```
           <?php        

       if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
     {


       ?>
            <html>

        <table align="center">
              <tr>

                 <td>
                    <input  class="input" type="text" name="uname" id="uid"  placeholder="Username"  >
                </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>

                <td>
                    <input  class="input" type="password" name="pwd" id="pid" placeholder="Password" >
                </td>
            </tr>

              <tr>
                <td> <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="" > </td>
            </tr>
      </table>

     <?PHP 

      }        

      else
   {

//If you are submitting the form insert the details into database

       $Username = $_POST['uname'];
          $Password = $_POST['pwd'];

            session_start();



     If (!(empty($Username) && empty($Password))) 
      {

      $model = new UsersModel();

      $rowsCount = $model->checkUser($Username,$Password,$User_Type);


       if ($rowsCount!=0)
       {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $Username;

        header("location:loggedin.php");

         } else 
        {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Enter username and password correctly");
        window.location.href="LoginViewController.php";</script>';
        }
        }

         }
          ?>
```

Here is the logged-in.php code that what i am working on it...

```
       <?php

          header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
           header("Pragma: no-cache");
           header("Expires: Fri, 4 Jun 2010 12:00:00 GMT");

               include('GenericClasses/GenericCollectionClass.php');
               include('Models/UsersModel.php');
               include('DataObjects/Users.php');
               include('DatabaseAccess/DBHandler.php');

         session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
      {
       header('Location: LoginViewController.php');
        exit();
        }
         echo '"<div style="background:white; text-align:right"> Login as:'.$_SESSION['user'].'
     <a href="LogoutViewController.php" style="text-align:right">Logout</a></div>"';


      ?>
```

Any suggestions are acceptable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loginController you need to check if session variable is set.If so then redirect the user to the member page or similar..

This might work

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("location : member.php");
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried the answer.. but i am unable to get redirection... why it is not redirecting ... and it simply showing a blank white page..

Comment: The problem may be u are echoing something before the header function..You may use meta-http redirect also...Make sure that you don't echo anything before using header..This is just a hint at on what can be done...If you are using codeigniter then they have a function called redirect(args)..you can use that function,too

Comment: I removed the echo statement... after that also it is not redirecting.. Here i am following some mvc architecture given by my trainer and i am new to this... if you have any experience in that help me to fix this problem..

Answer (score 1):

The `session_unset()` before the `session_start()`  in the logged-in.php file, remove all your session data.

Comment: Try to put a `print_r($_SESSION); die();`  after the `session_start() ` to check if the code is being executed and what $_SESSION contains.

Comment: it's taking the name of session user...."Array ( [user] => raju )" while i used the print_r.... in Loggedin.php

Comment: So it seems the data is on it..., strange. Try changing the var name e.g. `$_SESSION['foovar']` in the controller and in the loggedin.php to see if 'user' is a reserved var or something. You can also try on the condition `if($_SESSION['user'] == "")` (or even `if($_SESSION['foovar'] == "")` , it should work if you are storing strings

Answer (score 0):

`session_unset()` before `session_start()` gets rid of all current session variables, so you're deleting `$_SESSION['username']` before it's checked.

Also it seems like you're using some sort of framework or an MVC-like system that most frameworks have but then you're using your own extremely basic authentication system? Why not just use one of the popular frameworks out there and modify that? All the major ones have their own secure authentication system built in and they typically will have loads of community-made packages that introduce new features to the system.

Comment: I removed the session_unset().... and run that program again... after done it also no change in result.. Here I am following frame work given by my Lead and i am new to that..... If you know anything about frame work send me the link i will check them... and it will helpful in future..

Comment: Most popular PHP frameworks now are probably: Laravel, Symfony, CakePHP, CodeIgniter, Yii, and Zend. I personally use Laravel and I like it the most.